# Only a single copy is executing

Tags: ansible

I have these lines in a .yml file:

```
- name: copy nagios libraries
  copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_disk dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
  copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_load dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
  copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_mem.pl dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.pl owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
  copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_procs dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
  copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_swap dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_swap owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
  copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_users dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
```

Only the last one seems to be working.

Thanks for the downvote, very constructive.  You are an asset to the site, no doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, each of the copies seems to require being in a separate task, here's one way to do it:

```
- name: copy nagios libraries
  copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_disk dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
- copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_load dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
- copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_mem.pl dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mem.pl owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
- copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_procs dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
- copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_swap dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_swap owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
- copy: src=binaries/nagios/check_users dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
```

I found another way to solve the problem, which is a bit slicker:

```
- name: copy nagios libraries
  copy: src={{ item }} dest=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/ owner=nagios group=nagios mode=0755
  with_fileglob:
    - binaries/nagios/*
```